# OpenSeaDragon image viewer using image from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, openseadragon, deepzoom

I have thousands of high-resolution images that I would like to display on my website. I would like to select an image from Google Drive, dynamically tile the image, and display it on the website using OpenSeaDragon. Is that possible? If so, how do I go about it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you get a link to the image on Google Drive? I assume so. Given that, you have a few options:

1. Paste the URL into https://openseadragon.github.io/openseadragonizer/. This should be plenty fine, as long as your image isn't terribly big; it loads the whole image and then tiles it in memory.
2. If your image is very large, you can paste its URL into https://zoomhub.net/, where it'll tile it on the server.
3. If you want to make your own viewer, follow the instructions on https://openseadragon.github.io/docs/. For the image tile source, try https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/tilesource-image/; this is what option 1 above uses.
4. If you're making your own viewer, and the images are too big to work with the simple image tile source, you'll want something like https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/tilesource-dzi/. You'll need to do the conversion yourself using something from https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/creating-zooming-images/.

Comment: This is an example of one of my images https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GeBOBzST-fypXHJ5Nygwaz91sBK8jyw3  -- When I place it on openseadragonizer, it says that the image can't be retrieved even though I am able to open the image. familysearch.org is a good example of what I what to imitate. They get an image probably from Amazon and tile it on their server.

Comment: You need to get a direct link to the image itself, not just to its page on Google Drive. Looks like this post has info on that: https://www.labnol.org/google-drive-image-hosting-220515

Comment: This is what I envision but I don't know how to do it or whether it is even possible to do. I use an image tiling program in Google Cloud Computing where the input is an image from Google Drive and the output is DZI files in Google Cloud Storage. Then the DZI files are served to the user (CDN) where the file is open wirh SeaDragon. The command would be something like this --> imagetilingprogram -input Google_Drive_File_ID -output Cloud_Storage_DZI files -- Thanks!

Comment: That certainly all seems possible! I'm not familiar with those services though, so I can't direct you on how to proceed. As for the tiling program itself, the link I shared above has a number of options. My general preference is VIPS.